# Query or delete assets when there's relationship with cases

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, related-list, asset

Cases can be related to assets- there's a list of cases with an asset. But there's no relationship - both on case and asset there's no lookup or master field! Even more, when I change account related to a case- asset is still linked. And there's no entitlement.

Which brings me to 2 questions:

- how to query asset / cases related to each other? How list of cases is pulled to asset if there's no relationship field? `select id, (select id from cases) from asset` doesn't work
- is there a way to delete asset without deleting cases (can't delete as 'asset is associated with the following cases..' error)?

Comment: I'm not an user of Assets or Cases, but Case object does have an Asset lookup in it.

Comment: @MauricioOliveira exactly, that is strange- querying case object with `assetid` or `asset.id` shows error and documentation says there's no relationship with asset [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm), and still case object has an asset lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical org, I'd expect an Asset to initially get associated to an Account through either an Opportunity or a Contract. That's what usually sets the SLA. I would recommend that you try working through those objects to see if the relationships you're looking for begin to appear when you query through one of them.

BTW, you may find these links to [Asset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm) and [Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) in the Object Reference helpful to you.

**EDIT:**

From the Object Reference for Asset (follow link above):

> Use this object to track assets previously sold into customer accounts. With asset tracking, a client application can quickly determine which products were previously sold or are currently installed at a specific account. You can also create hierarchies of assets using the Parent Asset field. An asset hierarchy can contain up to 10,000 assets.

Additionally, from the SOAP API Developer Guide in the Data Model section under [Sales Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm), you'll see the following UML diagram that shows the relationship between Assets and Cases. I hope this helps you better understand this relationship.

[image: Sales Objects - Cases to Assets]

Comment: Still doesn't make sense- how case is associated with an asset if there're multiple assets? Case doesn't have OpportuntiyId or AssetId field- though relationship exists

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. Actually I figured out even though I was an sys administrator it was a permission issue which I didn't suspect was the case